# Grep file and extract value in ruby

Tags: ruby, awk, grep

How would I go about grepping a file to extract an IP address to place into another file?

This command works in bash, however I'm trying to port it over to ruby:

```
 grep "\b22/open" "/results/nmap_tcp_service_scan.gnmap" | awk '{print $2}' > /results/service_ssh
```

The file with the content that I'm grepping and placing into `service_ssh` looks like this:

```
Host: 10.10.10.1 (DD-WRT)   Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh//Dropbear sshd 0.52 (protocol 2.0)/, 53/open/tcp//domain//dnsmasq 2.45/, 80/open/tcp//http//DD-WRT milli_httpd/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https?///    Ignored State: closed (996) OS: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (Linux 2.6.24)   Seq Index: 204  IP ID Seq: All zeros
Host: 10.10.10.135 (Harmony)    Ports: 5222/open/tcp//xmpp-client//Openfire/, 8088/open/tcp//radan-http?///, 8222/open/tcp//unknown///  Ignored State: closed (997) OS: Linux 2.6.17 - 2.6.36   Seq Index: 203  IP ID Seq: All zeros
Host: 10.10.10.144 (time-capsule)   Ports: 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn?///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 548/open/tcp//afp//Apple Time Capsule AFP (name: justins-time-capsule; protocol 3.3)/, 5009/open/tcp//airport-admin//Apple AirPort or Time Capsule admin/, 10000/open/tcp//snet-sensor-mgmt?///    Ignored State: closed (995) OS: Apple AirPort Extreme WAP or Time Capsule NAS device (NetBSD 4.99), or QNX 6.5.0    Seq Index: 210  IP ID Seq: Incremental
```

Doing this in ruby finds the right lines and creates an array:

```
 open('nmap_tcp_service_scan.gnmap').grep(/\b22\/open/)
```

Results:

```
 => ["Host: 10.10.10.1 (DD-WRT)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//Dropbear sshd 0.52 (protocol 2.0)/, 53/open/tcp//domain//dnsmasq 2.45/, 80/open/tcp//http//DD-WRT milli_httpd/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https?///\tIgnored State: closed (996)\tOS: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (Linux 2.6.24)\tSeq Index: 204\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n", "Host: 10.10.10.111 (changeme)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4+deb7u2 (protocol 2.0)/, 10000/open/tcp//http//MiniServ 1.760 (Webmin httpd)/\tIgnored State: closed (998)\tOS: Linux 3.2 - 4.0\tSeq Index: 261\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n"]
```

However, now I need to extract the IP address and place it into a file that would end up looking like:

```
 10.10.10.1
 10.10.10.2
 10.10.10.3
 ...etc
```

Comment: You can use a regex to get ip address from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From result array (say `r`):

```
=> ["Host: 10.10.10.1 (DD-WRT)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//Dropbear sshd 0.52 (protocol 2.0)/, 53/open/tcp//domain//dnsmasq 2.45/, 80/open/tcp//http//DD-WRT milli_httpd/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https?///\tIgnored State: closed (996)\tOS: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (Linux 2.6.24)\tSeq Index: 204\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n", "Host: 10.10.10.111 (changeme)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4+deb7u2 (protocol 2.0)/, 10000/open/tcp//http//MiniServ 1.760 (Webmin httpd)/\tIgnored State: closed (998)\tOS: Linux 3.2 - 4.0\tSeq Index: 261\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n"]
```

---

Use a regex to extract ip address from each string in this array. Do something like:

```
arr_of_ip = []
r = ["Host: 10.10.10.1 (DD-WRT)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//Dropbear sshd 0.52 (protocol 2.0)/, 53/open/tcp//domain//dnsmasq 2.45/, 80/open/tcp//http//DD-WRT milli_httpd/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https?///\tIgnored State: closed (996)\tOS: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (Linux 2.6.24)\tSeq Index: 204\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n", "Host: 10.10.10.111 (changeme)\tPorts: 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4+deb7u2 (protocol 2.0)/, 10000/open/tcp//http//MiniServ 1.760 (Webmin httpd)/\tIgnored State: closed (998)\tOS: Linux 3.2 - 4.0\tSeq Index: 261\tIP ID Seq: All zeros\n"]
pattern = "Host:\s([^\s]+)"
re = Regexp.new(pattern)
r.each do |s|
  arr_of_ip << s.scan(re)
end

arr_of_ip.flatten!
```

Produces output:

```
["10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.111"]
```

[Regex test](http://rubular.com/r/0gJZcS2Edr)

Comment: Wow, that's some awesomeness!